# How to convert from virtual address to physical address and back?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

I'm given a task to write an application that will talk to a device. However this is not a driver since device is still being developed and the application is intended to exercises its first revision.

We will be talking with a device through /dev/mem. We will have all the privileges to do that. We know that this is not the right way to do it (i.e. need to use a driver) but again this is just a test to make sure that device development is on schedule and it actually works.

The communication protocol has read and write operations specified. The problem is that all the addresses are physical. Here is what is meant by it.

If a host wants to write to a device it needs to give a physical address of the data which needs to be written. If a host needs to read from a device it needs to give a physical address of the buffer where data can be placed by the device.

Say my interface the following functions:

```
WriteToDevice(void *ptrToDataToWriteToADevice, unsgined numBytes);
ReadFromDevice(void *whereToPlaceDataReadFromADevice, unsigned numBytes);
```

`ptrToDataToWriteToADevice` and `whereToPlaceDataReadFromADevice` are both in application space, i.e. not  physical addresses. How do I tell to my device to find these pointers in physical memory?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd guess you can't really give out translated virtual pointers without locking the particular memory pages. Maybe some `shm` functions can be used for locking down memory areas from virtual to physical?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Can you elaborate more. I'm not new to Linux but I never worked with drivers, devices, or kernel directly.

Comment: I was thinking that virtual memory of a process is not really locked onto any particular physical memory, but it can be swapped around. Thus if a device accesses a memory area, that area needs to be "locked" to hold a particular virtual area, which must not be swapped away during the access. The alternative is to have the device locked into a physical memory area, with the (virtual memory sited) process doing the read/write.

Comment: if your device is a pci device then it will not be able to dma into memory without it being enabled for bus master at least. Even then, the physical address you see from the cpu will be different to the bus address seen from the device. Then there can be an IOMMU to complicate that mapping even more.

Comment: @meuh Let's say then that I need to write a driver for this device. How would I develop one? If I understand you correctly then there is no way for me to talk to a device. Assume that I have access to all the Linux tools that I need.

Comment: a good online book is [Linux Device Drivers](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). It is outdated, but explains a lot of necessary background, and has simple example code, some of which may need revising, but you can google for changes in the kernel API, which is always a moving target.

Comment: @meuh My device is memory mapped. What if I map `/dev/mem` to a file descriptor, using mmap and then talk to it directly using `read` and `write`. Will that work? I'm trying to find a simple solution without complicating things too much.

Comment: mmap can work for direct access; make sure from C to declare pointers as volatile. Beware of read/write as you don't know what size (byte, short, long) the accesses will be made with finally, and some hardware will want aligned addresses and 32 bit data only, for example.

Comment: @meuh Can you elaborate more on read/write access? What do you mean by byte, short, long?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41775/discussion-between-flashburn-and-meuh).

Comment: sorry, I meant read() and write() on the /dev/mem file descriptor. if you do a read() of length 4, it might result in 4 separate reads of 1 byte on the pci bus.